# Contar o numero de caracteres e inserir um novo em uma determinada posição, em uma string?

Tags: android

Tenho as duas strings:

`String num_tel1 = "03184872882"` e a `String num_tel2 = "84872882"`. Elas tem 11 e 8 caracteres, respectivamente. Como faço para contar esta quantidade de caracteres e, se tiver uma String com 11 caracteres (num_tel1), inserir o número 9, logo após o 031 e, se tiver 8 caracteres, inserir o numero 9, na primeira posição, ou seja, antes do primeiro 8 (num_tel2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método [StringBuilder::Insert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,%20boolean)) para inserir o número 9 na posição que você quer de acordo com o tamanho da sua `String`.

Podemos fazer assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  System.out.println(formatString("03184872882"));
  System.out.println(formatString("84872882")); 
}

public static String formatString(String s) {
  StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(s);
  sBuilder.insert(s.length() == 11 ? 3 : 0, "9");
  return sBuilder.toString();
}
```

**Output**:

```
031984872882
984872882
```

Veja que eu utilizei um operador ternário para inserir o número 9 na posição correta de acordo com o tamanho da string. Basicamente, o operador ternário faz isso:

```
if(s.length() == 11) sBuilder.insert(3, "9"); // Insere o número 9 na quarta posição da `String`, depois do DDD.
else sBuilder.insert(0, "9"); // Insere o número na primeira posição da string.
```

Comment: obrigado! Só um adendo à resposta, o operador ternário, dentro do insert, da stringbuilder, pelo menos no caso do android studio, não funcionou. Mas era isso que queria.

Comment: Hmm... eu tinha testado aqui e funcionou normalmente, que estranho! Mas estou feliz que ajudei de alguma maneira. Valeu! :))

Comment: Também achei estranho, mas trocando para os operadores normais funcionou normalmente. Enfim, agradeço novamente!

Answer (score 1):

Eu tenho uma função que sempre uso, que é pra validar telefone. Vou colocar aqui o que precisa pra ela funcionar que eu vou tentar te dar uma luz. No caso está tudo static porque é uma classe Util que eu tenho. Modifiquei ela para seu caso blz:

```
public static final String TELEFONE_REGEX = "([0-9]{4}[0-9]{3}[1-9]9?(\\d{2})?).*";

public static String getTelefone(String telefone, Context context) {
        Pattern phoneRegex = Pattern.compile(TELEFONE_REGEX);

        telefone = reverseStr(telefone.replaceAll("\\D", ""));

        Matcher m = phoneRegex.matcher(telefone);

        if (m.matches())
            telefone = m.group(1);

        telefone = reverseStr(telefone);

        if (telefone.length() == 8)
            telefone = "9" + telefone;
        if (telefone.length() == 11)
            telefone = telefone.substring(0,3) + "9" + telefone.substring(3, telefone.length()-1);

        return telefone;
    }

public static String reverseStr(String input) {
        String output = "";
        for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) output += input.charAt(i);
        return output;
    }
```

Essa função valida se o input é um telefone mesmo, e verifica de forma inversa.